# How to use local fonts using font-face mixin in vaadin?

Tags: sass, vaadin

I want to use Roboto Condensed font as local, not from web.

Like

```
@include font-face('Roboto Condensed', '../../../../../../styles/systemfont/*', 300, 300i, 400, 400i, 700&'subset=cyrillic, cyrillic-ext, latin-ext');
```

But this seems not to work

And I try to avoid to use

```
@StyleSheet("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext")
```

in my UI class

Comment: Could you please describe, what is not working?  E.g. you get a 404 etc.

Comment: i something put wrong, and compiler can't compile it that is my problem

Comment: Then please add all the relevant information to that question

Comment: Continuing what @cfrick suggested, please include the path inside your project where your theme and where the font are located

Comment: Maybe worth trying to download manually and specify full path for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me. I am packaging my font in Jar like Vaadin is doing with their Valo theme and then I include that as a dependency through pom.xml.

Place font files (ttf etc.) in your theme folder. You can add more urls to `@font-face` section if there are different types of fonts.

Folder structure looks like this

VAADIN/themes/my-style/styles.scss
VAADIN/themes/my-style/my-style.scss
VAADIN/themes/my-style/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf
...

styles.scss

```
@import "my-style.scss";
.my-valo {
    @include my-style;
}
```

my-style.scss

```
@import "my other files ..."
@mixin my-valo {
    ...
}

@mixin MyRobotoFont($weight, $style, $fontWeight: 400, $fontStyle: normal) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
        src: url('fonts/RobotoCondensed-#{$weight}#{$style}.ttf' format('truetype');
        font-weight: $fontWeight;
        font-style: $fontStyle;
    }
}

@include MyRobotoFont($weight: Regular, $style: "");
@include MyRobotoFont($weight: Bold, $style: "");
@include MyRobotoFont($weight: Bold, $style: Italic);
@include MyRobotoFont($weight: "", $style: Italic);
@include MyRobotoFont($weight: Light, $style: "");
@include MyRobotoFont($weight: Light, $style: Italic);
```

Somewhere in your scss files

```
font-family: MyRobotoFont
font-weight: 400;
font-style: italic;
```

Or in _variables.scss

```
$v-font-family: MyRobotoFont, arial, sans-serif
```